# Classifier with heterogeneous data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, classification

I have a l2-dimensional data set of 1000 samples composed  of 5 temperature values,
5 price values, one integer value representing a judgement by a human expert (undecided=0, good=1, bad=2, danger=4) and a binary decision  variable  that I want to learn to predict.

How can I find a classifier than can cope with this heterogeneous data ?

I was thinking about building one classifier for each possible human judgement (0,1,2,4), so 4 classifiers.
So for each human judgement value, I would:
 - center and reduce the temperature and price values
 - maybe use PCA to remove some irrelevant features
 - use a machine learning method for classification (like multi layers neural networks or SVM)

Is my approach correct ? (what if there were 1000 possible human judgements instead of 4 ?)

Answer (score 2):

A typical way of encoding categories for SVMs or ANNs is the 1-of-C encoding:

- [Neural Network FAQ](ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ.html) - [Subject: How should categories be encoded?](ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ2.html#A_cat)
- [A Practical Guide to Support Vector Classification](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf) - 2.1 Categorical Feature

Generally almost every classifier can deal with heterogeneous data. But you have to preprocess the inputs (scale, normalize, ...). There should be plenty of hints in the links I gave you.